# Multiple class instances

Tags: objective-c

There's the instance1 and instance2 of the same class (RandomClass).

I want to set the `instance1.string` as `@"instance 1 string"` and `instance2.string` as `@"instance2 2 string"`, and access them differently, but looks like when I set the instance2.string the instance1.string also changes it value. I'm using sharedInstance method;

Something like:

```
RandomClass *instance1 = [RandomClass sharedInstance];
instance1.string = @"instance 1 string";

RandomClass *instance2 = [RandomClass sharedInstance];
instance2.string = @"instance 2 string";

NSLog(@"%@", instance2.string); // wich results 'instance 2 string'    
NSLog(@"%@", instance1.string); // wich results 'instance 2 string'
```

As you can see, the instance2.string changes the instance1 string value.

Is there any way to create different instances, separately, dealing with the class objects as unique values (accessed by it own instance)?

Comment: if you want to use multiple instances, you should create (`alloc`, `init` or `new` or `copy`) different instances. The point of the singleton class you could save some memory and time, if you are using the common instance of the same class in cases when it makes sense. you should design the pattern for you specific application carefully not randomly, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not valid because you doesn't have two instances of the same class, you have only one singleton instance. Note that `[RandomClass sharedInstance]` return always the same instance, you only have two references for it.

The normal way to create instances is

```
[[RandomClass alloc] init...]
```

Please don't use the term `thread` in the context of class and instances, this only makes the problem more confusing.

I believe you should visit some Obj-C tutorials or some OOP tutorials first.

Comment: I'm sorry for the thread term. As a non-english native is hard to find a term to define multiple instances, separately. I edited the question.

Comment: @Alberto The term you are looking for is "instance". Every instance is an individual entity. That's why I am advising you to go through an OOP tutorial first. You don't understand well what is an "instance" and what is a "reference" (or "pointer"). The code from your question is absolutely correct and expected.

Answer (score 0):

`instance1` and `instance2` are referencing the same object as `[RandomClass sharedInstance]`. If you modify any of them, all of the changes will be take affect on the original `sharedInstance`.

If you want two different objects, you must instantiate two times (if `RandomClass` provides any initializer method):

```
RandomClass *instance1 = [[RandomClass alloc] init];
instance1.string = @"instance 1 string";

RandomClass *instance2 = [[RandomClass alloc] init];
instance2.string = @"instance 2 string";

NSLog(@"%@", instance1.string); // wich results 'instance 1 string'    
NSLog(@"%@", instance2.string); // wich results 'instance 2 string'
```

(By the way, `RandomClass` looks like a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), so there might be no way to instantiate multiple objects.)

Comment: That's something that I realized. Is there a solution to multiple instances?